# Downvoting out of spite?

Tags: discussion

In a recent thread [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104201/prove-for-all-n-geq-0-that-3-n36n211n6/104209#104209) I downvoted an answer for the reason as explained in my comment. However the user that posted the answer that I downvoted then went on to downvote the answers of Myself,pedja and Benjamin Lim (me). The reason this user downvoted the three answers (as he said in the same comment posted on all three answers is that ):

"-1 good answer, but such a simple question seems to be homework and it can't be a problem with mathematician. and you shouldn't provide full answer."

I honestly find this comment to be non-constructive and have flagged for moderator attention. The comment assumes too many things like "seems to be homework" and "can't be a problem with mathematician". Can the moderators do something about this (such as warn this user of such behaviour)?

Thanks.

$\textbf{Edit:}$ I notice Saeed's answer has been deleted. Saeed did you delete it or was it the moderators that deleted it?

Comment: Implicit in the question is also "should the moderators do something about this?" While I personally find such a reason for downvotes to be quite silly, if the user does hold a conviction that "posting complete solutions to suspected homework questions is bad", he should be allowed to vote as such. After all, votes are one way for users to express their opinion on how the site grows.

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks for your input.

Comment: @WillieWong, I think your opinion is quite silly.

Comment: He did.${}{}{}$

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks perhaps he felt it received too many downvotes.

Comment: @BenjaminLim I saw your deleted comment; it is explained [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2687/why-do-some-posts-appear-faded-out).

Comment: @ZevChonoles Thanks Zev.

Comment: @Saeed Why have you deleted your answer below and the comments you left on the answers of pedja, Myself and Benjamin Lim?

Comment: Would you like to know why the comment @Myself left on your answer has been upvoted (+8), your answer downvoted 9 times and your answer here on meta downvoted (I believe the last time I saw) 4 times?

Comment: It upvoted 8 because people want say they agree with that my answer was not useful and comment was rude, but they didn't think about my answer, like you (at first glance) but 3 other people upvoted my answer to say it is good, also when I asked which part of my comment was rude, myself doesn't mentioned valuable response. I understand shouldn't expect from small mind people to tell me why my answer is not useful or why my comment was rude (you wrote my first (rude!) comment), may be currently I'm rude but this is natural response to non logical manners of such people.

Comment: Would you like to know why such a simple answers got 20+ upvotes? really they were beautiful math?

Comment: No, @saeed, I don't want to hear anything from you.

Comment: This discussion has clearly become unproductive. 1) Saeed's answer on the question itself doesn't deserve all of these downvotes - it isn't *wrong*. 2) Saeed, stop calling everything "silly". In case you did not notice, Willie was supporting your "right" to downvote. Does anyone disagree that the matter is now settled? Ben brought this issue up to ask the moderators about it. The moderators have responded. As long as everyone avoids insulting everyone else from now on, I don't see any reason for further concern here. In fact, I think it'd be best if we closed this question, at minimum.